# Emscripten SDL Compilation faliure

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, emscripten

I'm new to emscripten; several days ago I've downloaded it just to try to make a port of a game to JS.

Anyway, after some steps, I'm having this issue now (on Ubuntu 16.04 STL).
By following build steps [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#building-projects), first of all, I've set environment variables with
`source ./emsdk_env.sh` and then I've tried to configure the project with `emconfigure ./configure` in the project directory. When checking for tools emscripten needs, I've got this error:

```
checking for SDL... no
configure: error: Package requirements (sdl2 >= 2.0.1) were not met:

No package 'sdl2' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SDL_CFLAGS
and SDL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR:root:Configure step failed with non-zero return code 1! Command line: ['./configure'] at ...
```

So I've tried to set that variable with the following command:
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`
This is where actually `sdl2.pc` is located on my machine, but it didn't help.

So then I've set the following variables that `emconfigure` needed:

```
export SDL_PATH=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDL_LIBS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDL_CFLAGS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDLNET_LIBS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDLNET_CFLAGS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDLMIXER_LIBS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
export SDLMIXER_CFLAGS=/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h
```

and relaunched `emconfigure ./configure` which has completed well.
So the next step is `emmake make` that gives me the following error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0'
Making all in textscreen
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen'
Making all in fonts
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen/fonts'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen/fonts'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen'
  CC       txt_conditional.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/emcc", line 11, in <module>
    python_selector.run(__file__)
  File "/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/tools/python_selector.py", line 38, in run
    sys.exit(run_by_import(filename, main) if on_allowed_version() else run_by_subprocess(filename))
  File "/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/tools/python_selector.py", line 13, in run_by_import
    return getattr(importlib.import_module(os.path.basename(filename)), main)()
  File "/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/emcc.py", line 1345, in run
    assert header.endswith(HEADER_ENDINGS), 'if you have one header input, we assume you want to precompile headers, and cannot have source files or other inputs as well: ' + str(headers) + ' : ' + header
AssertionError: if you have one header input, we assume you want to precompile headers, and cannot have source files or other inputs as well: ['/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.38/system/include/SDL/SDL.h', 'txt_conditional.c'] : txt_conditional.c
Makefile:447: recipe for target 'txt_conditional.o' failed
make[3]: *** [txt_conditional.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen'
Makefile:467: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0/textscreen'
Makefile:585: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ustym/Documents/Projects/chocolate-doom-3.0.0'
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

that means, I assume, that `SDL_PATH`, `SDL_LIBS`, `SDL_CFLAGS`... variables weren't set correctly. Or maybe I just need to precompile that headers in the SDL directory.

One last thing: if I skip setting SDL variables and the configuration step and just launch `emmake make`, the compilation goes well, but then, `emcc` command gives me
`WARNING:root:    .o is not valid LLVM bitcode`
for all generated `.o` files. And that actually makes sense.

So I'm pretty stuck here. Somebody can tell me how to set correctly `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` for emscripten or if i really need to precompile those headers in the SDL directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, include or, even worse, library directories (`-I` and `-L`) to host libraries' ones looks like awful idea to me: Emscripten object files contain LLVM bitcode (and not host machine code), its `.so` files AFAIK contain bitcode as well. It is that bitcode that gets translated to JS, not host machine code. So you need to build your program's dependencies with Emscripten by yourself (and should most probably not install them to the host system). Fortunately, there are some official *Emscripten ports* (see [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#using-libraries)) for details.

Emscripten has its own implementation of SDL v1 (that you probably tried to use manually), but your program seems to require SDL2. Good news: you probably just need to pass `-s USE_SDL=2` to `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` when `configure`ing (see later on the link above for information on SDL2 port). Bad news: something may not be fully ported. But I successfully used it to some extent.

When you have `configure`d on host and make with `emmake` you probably had compiler paths among other parameters adjusted by `emconfigure` and `emmake` already baked into generated Makefile by `./configure` not controlled by `emconfigure`, so host `gcc`/`clang` just generated machine code.